# Как лучше искать игровые сервера в локальной сети?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сеть

Пишу мультиплеерную игру с возможностью поиска серверов в локальной сети.
По всем примерам, что я находил, везде поиск хостов идёт линейно. С `timeout` в одну секунду поиск получается в 4 минуты. Это слишком медленно. Я попробовал сделать через запуск потоков (Пример):

```
int timeout=1000;
for (int i=1;i<254;i++){
    String host=subnet + "." + i;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
                    System.out.println(host+" found");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

В результате все сервера находится за пару секунд. Но я уверен, что есть какой-то подвох. Как тогда правильно? Чем может быть небезопасно это решение?

Comment: При большом количестве соединений может зависнуть сетевое оборудование типа роутера. Я бы поставил ограничение в 50 потоков.

Comment: Я бы для определения присутствия серверов прослушивал бы отдельный UDP-сокет на серверах. А тот кто ищет послал бы пару раз один единственный пакет "кто в сети", на широковещательный адрес данной подсети (можно просто на 255.255.255.255). Все сервера в пределах локальной сети увидят данный пакет и ответят